# Скрытие части кода до авторизации в Angular 5

Tags: angular

У приложения в свободном доступе только один route - login Переход к остальное защищено проверкой jsonwebtoken. Однако, если не авторизованному пользователю, находясь на странице login, посмотреть скрипты, например через DevTool Chrome - sources, то можно увидеть названия функций компонентов, сервисов, параметров и значений.
Можно как то это содержимое скрывать до авторизации?

Comment: если использовать lazy loading то пользователь не увидит скрипты, до того пока не авторизуется. Даже если видит, какая разница? Что он по твоему с ними сделает?

Comment: В сервисах видны вcе маршруты Rest api. которые используются, также из классов видны свойства, которые передаются в REST API

Comment: ну и что? это все можно в нетворке увидеть)

Comment: Как http запросы, на api? Да. Но только если пользователь авторизован